# MS Access 2013 DoCmd for on click function returns error

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013, ms-access-forms

[Shows the number to be clicked and the resulting form that opens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3MJZ.png)

Simply put...I am trying to open a specific record based on the record number that is clicked in the form.  From a search criteria form, clicking "Search" opens another form in database view listing the search results.  On click of the record number, I need that specific record to open in the assigned form.

Note:

- My form was created from a query and is set to database view - this works
- The record number (VDMR Number) is set to display as a hyperlink - this works
- On click of record number, the correct form opens but it is a blank record - Problem

My brain has melted several times over the past two days searching for a fix.

Here is the code I am using:

```
>DoCmd.OpenForm "QPF-45 (11/2012)", , , "VDMR_Number =" & Me.VDMR__
```

Comment: Please tell us, which error will be shown. This could be important.

Comment: With the Code I'm using there is no error.  It just doesn't open the record number that is clicked on. It opens a blank form in "Add" mode.

Comment: I added a snipit to my original question to help explain.

Comment: Is the field named `VDMR Number` or `VDMR_Number`?

Comment: VDMR Number, the code didn't work without the underscore inbetween.

Comment: FYI I change the name of my control source, which previously was "VDMR #" and the pound symbol was causing problems. :                                                                 
`Private Sub VDMR_Number_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm "QPF-45 (11/2012)", , , "VDMR_Number =" & Me.VDMR_Number

End Sub`

Comment: have you checked the settings of the form you are opening?  If it is set to data entry = true, it won't show the existing record you are passing through.

Answer (score 1):

> VDMR Number, the code didn't work without the underscore in between

Neither did it with the underscore, because that's not a field name of yours.

So, either change the field name to not have a space, or wrap it in brackets:

```
 DoCmd.OpenForm "QPF-45 (11/2012)", , , "[VDMR Number] =" & Me.VDMR__
```

And refrain from using unreadable control names like "VDMR__"